# NAT Between TUN and Ethernet Network Interfaces

Tags: iptables, routing, nat, tun

There's a detailed explanation of the setup and my debugging efforts so far, but the main question is at the bottom.

I have a setup like so:

- *Machine A* has two network interfaces: `eth0` (`192.168.159.60`) and `mesh0` (`10.255.0.1`), where `eth0` has a route to 0.0.0.0/0 and `mesh0` is a TUN interface being used in a mesh network.
- *Machine B* has one network interface: `mesh0` (`10.255.0.2`), where `mesh0` is also TUN interface.
- `mesh0` on *A* and `mesh0` on *B* are wirelessly connected.

I would like to be able to send traffic from *B*, through *A*, to some external machine. Essentially, *A* is a gateway for *B*.

`ip route` for *A*:

```
default via 192.168.144.1 dev eth0
10.255.0.0/16 dev mesh0 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.0.1
10.255.0.2 via 10.255.0.2 dev mesh0 proto 100 src 10.255.0.1 metric 2 onlink
192.168.144.0/20 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.159.60
```

`ip route` for *B*:

```
default via 10.255.0.1 dev mesh0 proto 100 src 10.255.0.2 metric 2 onlink 
10.255.0.0/16 dev mesh0 proto kernel scope link src 10.255.0.2 
10.255.0.1 via 10.255.0.1 dev mesh0 proto 100 src 10.255.0.2 metric 2 onlink
```

**Step 1:** Verify packets from *A* to *B*
The connection between *A* and *B* is working as expected. If I run `ping -I mesh0 8.8.8.8` on *B*, and I run `sudo tcpdump --interface mesh0` on *B*, it outputs:

```
21:08:59.701208 IP 10.255.0.2 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 43, seq 374, length 64
```

So I know that my packets are getting from *B* to *A*.

**Step 2:** Verify packet forwarding on *A*
Next, I checked whether *A* was forwarding the packets it received on `mesh0` to `eth0`. If I run `sudo tcpdump --interface eth0`, I see:

```
21:15:00.581098 IP 10.255.0.2 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 44, seq 5, length 64
```

So I know that the packet forwarding on *A* is working as expected. However, there is no corresponding ICMP echo reply. For some reason, the request is going out on `eth0`, but no response is coming back.

**Step 3:** Test the same ping from *A*
To confirm that it's not an issue with the external server or the `eth0` interface itself, I ran `ping -I eth0 8.8.8.8` **and** `sudo tcpdump --interface eth0` on *A*. The tcpdump shows:

```
21:12:45.878014 IP 192.168.159.60 > dns.google: ICMP echo request, id 11669, seq 6, length 64
21:12:45.882465 IP dns.google > 192.168.159.60: ICMP echo reply, id 11669, seq 6, length 64
```

And the ping succeeds. So, I know it's not an issue with the `eth0` interface or the server I'm trying to ping.

All of this leads me to the conclusion that the issue is with the next hop not knowing where to route the ICMP echo response to. Problem: I need NAT on *A* from `mesh0` to `eth0`.

**Question:**
How can implement NAT between `mesh0` and `eth0`, so that response packets from external machines (e.g. `8.8.8.8`) are routed back to `eth0` so they can be forwarded to `mesh0`?

Comment: Your question seems a bit weird to me. I mean, are you totally unaware that you can set up SNAT with iptables / nftables on Linux or what? Or are you looking for guides for their syntax or so? (It's essentially a one-liner especially in the case of iptables.)

Comment: The mentioned basic one-liner is `iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE`; it doesn't matter which interface packets were in, whether that's mesh0 or even eth0 itself; if they are destined to *output* eth0 they will be SNATed. Probably you'd want to restrict it to whatever neworks sits behind mesh0 (add `-s 10.255.0.0/24` or something like that). What is specific problem with that?

Comment: You can have either or both the `-s` and `-o` match btw. The `-o` match can sometimes be undesirable if the interface (name) changes from time to time.

Comment: @NikitaKipriyanov do you know the equivalent one-liner for nftables?

Comment: It is not possible to have easy one-liner for nftables — you need to create chains and everybody is free to give them names as they wish, whereas in iptables they are fixed. However, you can always change `iptables` to `iptables-translate` in any iptables command and it will give you a great hint how the corresponding nftables rule should look like.